# BNO055 unreliable on start-up, WRONG_START_BYTE errors?

Tags: c++, sensors, uart, motion-detection

I have been working with a BNO055 sensor chip in IMU mode. I am using the BOSCH library (not Adafruit) with the aid of some wrapper functions I have written. I read in Quaternion values through UART and have no problems getting reliable data if the chip provides them. However, every so often when I start the program I encounter one of the following situations:

1) The attempts to read from the chip return `WRONG_START_BYTE` errors for every read, since the reading is just a looping thread this continues until I exit the application.

2) I receive a single `RECEIVE_CHARACTER_TIMEOUT` error before entering the above looping `WRONG_START_BYTE` state.

3) I begin receiving `WRONG_START_BYTE` errors before some unexpected `WRITE_SUCCESS` responses, and then continue to read in what I can only assume is data that is no longer being read with the correct offset as it simply returns unknown errors (data being read does not match the expected values of response messages as set out in the datasheet).

This behavior has been very unpredictable and as I said only happens occasionally, but often enough to be a large reliability concern for my application. This also means that debugging this error has been very difficult as I can't consistently reproduce the behavior.

Any ideas what may be causing this? Happy to provide more information on request!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what the data stream has in it?  Also your code which parses it?

Comment: Data stream is read directly from /dev/ttyUSB0 and the code that parses it (as in converts the on wire bytes to something useful) is in the Bosch BNO055 library which I then invoke, unless you mean you want to see my read and write to port methods?

Comment: How about adding a bit of code so it displays the raw input stream (before any parsing)?  I am assuming this code you've written has not ever worked, right?

Comment: Which device are you using to inteface the BNO055?